# PJSIP library linker error ios

Tags: ios, libraries, pjsip

I followed the **pjsip** documentation and compile its different architecture for **ios**, after compilation it should built successfully but its giving me a linking error.
**ld: library not found for -lpjmedia-codec
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Please help me to sort out this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems that you haven't added 'libpjmedia-codec.a' to Xcode project

Comment: libpjmedia-codec.a' has been added to my project , and also link in build phases -> linker libraries .